# How to remove current path and/or timestamp from the prompt in Mobaxterm

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-11, mobaxterm

**Software**: MobaXTerm 23.2
**OS**: Windows 11

I'm using a Bash (Embedded) Local Shell Session in MobaXTerm. The prompt contains the date, the time stamp and the current folder, which leaves little space for my commands. How can I remove date and timestamp (and optionally current folder) from the prompt?

This is similar to

[How to prevent MobaXterm from prepending the path?](https://superuser.com/q/1170760/642458)

however:

1. the other question is about the CMD session. This is about the Bash (Embedded) Session.
2. One answer assumes I'm using the WSL (which I'm not). The other one mentions a file `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MobaXterm\slash\etc\profile` which doesn't exist in MobaXterm 23.2 (there's no `MobaXterm` folder at all, inside the `Documents` folder)

**EDIT**: the output of `echo "$PS1"` is

`\[\]$(_gp 1) \[\] \[▒\]▒▒ \D{%d/%m/%Y} \[\]\[▒\]▒\[\] \[▒\]▒▒ \D{%H:%M.%S} \[\]$(_gp 2)\[▒\]▒\[\]`

[image]

Comment: Please add the result of `echo "$PS1"` to your question